# How to determine why a query is taking longer on a production server than on a development machine?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a a query which only takes `0.004s` on my development machine (Windows 7 running WampServer on an HDD) but takes `0.057s` on my production server (CENTOS 6.5 running on an SSD) -- a difference of 14x. Both MySQL versions are the same.

The `explain` results are identical on both servers, as are the databases (I exported the database from my production server and imported it into my development machine). I also ran `optimize table` on both servers, and tried putting in `SQL_NO_CACHE`, but that didn't make a difference on either one.

Navicat shows this under the Profile tab:

**Production**

[image]

**Development**

[image]

The execution times for the queries are consistent on both servers.

The database versions are the same, the content is the same, and the `explain` results are the same. Is there any way to determine why the query is taking 14x longer on my production server?

EDIT: In an attempt to determine if the MySQL server is under load, I found the Process List area in Navicat and can see that there are only a few processes, all of which are for "Sleep" commands. So I don't think the production server is under any load.

Comment: If the indexes are up to date, then I would ask if there is a heavy load on the production server

Comment: @bowlturner There are less than half a dozen people viewing my website right now according to my analytics software, and I've re-run the queries 1-2 dozen times and it's always taken exactly the same amount of time (so I don't think it could be load, since most of those times the people on the site were bound to be on the same page). With that said, is there a way to check for sure?

Comment: I would suggest there are more rows on the production ? Most of the time is sorting the results on both

Comment: @exussum The databases are exactly the same. I exported it from production and imported into my development machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The production server seems to be slower in every parameter listed. There could be many factors involved, so you should check each one:

1. First of all, check if there is any other load on the production server. Is the server doing something else in the meanwhile? Use Linux command `top` to see running process and check if any of them is using a lot of computing power. Use the MySQL command `SHOW STATUS` to get info about the MySQL server status (memory, open tables, current connections, etc.)
2. Check the hardware: nowadays some desktop PCs are more powerful than cheap virtual servers (CPU, RAM frequency and access times, ...)
3. MySQL could use different settings in the two environments
4. Make sure you have the same indexes on both databases.